# Old Data on SFTP

Tags: mysql, backup, disk-space

There are several old files on an sftp of mine that date back to two years ago. These files are ingested into a MySQL database. I am wondering what to do with the old raw files. The reason I am asking is because I am running into disk-space issues on my server.

Comment: Compress them.  But that is only a short-term solution for disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what is your data retention policy?  Do you have cheap storage to put them on?  Can you test restore them and ask the business owner if they need to keep it?  If they do, do they have cheap slow or available storage to put it on?  If not, are they open to you putting it on Amazon Glacier or something like that?

This is really a business question.  Does the business value the old data.  Some do, some don't depending on the setup.  I typically keep backups for a long time and stick to quarterly/monthly backup archives that go back several years.  Outside of that I don't keep random backups that no one wants.

This is a good time for you to reach out to the business and define some data retention and acceptable data loss policies.  For example:

- Full backups for a minimum of x days
- Transaction/Diff backups for a minimum of x days that restore up to y minutes.
- Archives.  How often, where, and why?

Finally, test your backups and archive them if needed or delete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The client hasn't requested a recent analysis of that data but it would be nice to keep on hand if need be. I think that moving this data to our AWS configuration via Amazon Glacier is the ideal solution.

Comment: Great, if you would like though, you can get clarity on data retention as well, then reiterate the decisions in a meeting back to the business.  This way you're covered if they need a old backup and it doesn't exist.  For example they might ask for data from a month ago and if it isn't available they might all of a sudden forget the prior discussions.